# Could not build wheels for xattr, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pip, xattr

Trying to install this thing called Gailbot, but I'm quite a newbie at Python (coming from linguistics not coding background)
I did manage to solve some previous issues i had while trying to install but haven't been able to fix this?
i'd love some advice from people with more experience!
if relevant, my things arent installed on PATH as python warns me but i don't know how to move my things to PATH and have thus been using the commands `python -m pip install [whatever im trying to install]`

```
Building wheels for collected packages: xattr
  Building wheel for xattr (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for xattr (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\xattr
      copying xattr\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\xattr
      copying xattr\lib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\xattr
      copying xattr\lib_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\xattr
      copying xattr\pyxattr_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\xattr
      copying xattr\tool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\xattr
      copying xattr\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\xattr
      running build_ext
      generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\\Release\\_lib.c'
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      building '_lib' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\_lib.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\_lib.obj
      _lib.c
      build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\_lib.c(580): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/xattr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xattr
Failed to build xattr
ERROR: Could not build wheels for xattr, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

tried to install xattr on its own, same error
tried uninstalling and reinstalling python, didnt work
tried this thing i saw somewhere but i forgot  `python -m pip install xattr --no-cache-dir` but that didnt work either
tried looking for what sys/xattr.h is to download it or something but that led to nowhere
tried to install the latest sdk as per another post's solution, didn't work and same error

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/xattr/ "*Extended attributes are currently only available on Darwin 8.0+ (Mac OS X 10.4) and Linux 2.6+. Experimental support is included for Solaris and FreeBSD.*" The package cannot be compiled and used on w32.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/GailBot/ "*Operating System: MacOS*" Doesn't look promising either.

Comment: Oh my god I completely missed that. I might be dumb. Let me see if I can find someone with a Mac system 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to phd who pointed out that Gailbot is for MacOS and I'd been having issues because I was on Windows

Answer (score -1):

This error is occurring because the xattr package is trying to compile C extensions, but it cannot find the necessary headers to do so.

There are a few things you can try:

1. Install the Windows SDK. It seems like you've tried this already but make sure you install the latest SDK and also include the "C Runtime" component during installation.
2. Set up your environment variables to include the path to the Windows SDK include directories. This will make the header files accessible when compiling extensions.
3. Use a pre-compiled wheel for the xattr package instead of trying to compile it yourself. You can do this with:

`pip install xattr --find-links https://github.com/xattr/xattr/releases`

4. As a last resort, you can try installing xattr in a virtual environment instead of globally. This may isolate the issue and allow it to install successfully:

```
python -m venv venv  
venv\Scripts\activate
pip install xattr
```

Then you can install and run Gailbot within that virtual environment.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions. The error message suggests it's an issue compiling C extensions, so ensuring the necessary headers and SDK components are installed correctly should resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply! i did check and i do indeed seem to have the latest sdk (windows 11) as well as c runtime installed. i don't actually know how to do all the environment variables stuff (hence why my pip and python etc arent in PATH), and online guides are a little confusing for me :( the third method unfortunately led to the same error as my original post, and lastly for some reason I can't do the last as running scripts is apparently disabled on my system :(